# Algebraic closure of a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and $\bar{K}/K$ is infinite. Can we construct $K \subset K_1 \subset K_2 \subset \dots $ such that each extension is finite and $\bar{K}$ is the union of all $K_n$?  If in general this is not true, how about $K$ is a perfect field of characteristic $p >0$?

Comment: There is the obvious obstruction that $\dim_{K}\overline K >\aleph_0$ is a possibility: see for instance the fact that $\overline{\Bbb C(x)}$ contains the uncountable familiy of linearly independent elements $\{\sqrt{x-c}\}_{c\in\Bbb C}$ (the appropriate details having been dealt with). A similar instance in characteristic $p$ would be $\{\sqrt[p+1]{T-x_i}\}_{i\in\aleph_1}$ in $\overline{\Bbb F_p(T; (x_i\,:\, i\in\aleph_1))}$, though I don't know about the case of $K$ perfect.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Thank you, this may be false for $K$ perfect of char $p$. I guess this when I do an exercise, but I finally prove the exercise without this.